# UITabBar Transparent Background / Overlapping UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uitabbar

I have uploaded an image to illustrate the problem / desired effect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdEI.jpg

I have a UITabBar, with a custom background (including the multi-page / end of page effect - yes, directly on the UITabBar, because I need the shadow there). Works fine. I also have a UINavigationController for each of the tab items which subsequently controls a set of UITableViewControllers.

The design I have to implement requires a certain overlapping of the background and the UITabBar (see attached image). For the hell of it, I can't think of a smart way of implementing this.

I originally cut the multi-page effect sliver and attached it at the bottom of each UITableView (footer view), but while this sort of worked, it wasn't ideal in some situations.

I am really just looking for inspiration or suggestions on how you'd approach this.

I know how everyone likes to see code first, but I wouldn't know why, in this case. So let me know if you'd like to see parts of the code. No problem.

Did anyone solve this or implement this nicely? Links to apps in the AppStore accomplishing this really well is also helpful.

Comment: I'm actually working through the same problem right now. The major problem is that there's an opaque background that seems to always be present on the tab bar. I fear you'd have to override the drawRect method for the UITabBar, which is possible, but might break some Apple's rules.